# In the access 2007 append to query designer, can you still use references to form objects in the field table?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I'm a bit stumped. I have just migrated from access 97 to access 2007. In a certain append to query, the designer has Field: Expr1: [Forms]![NewSheet]![NewBatch#] for instance. This is supposed to mean that the NewBatch# textbox on the NewSheet form will contain the value that is inserted into the table that is being "Appended To", the table demanding an integer.

In the access 97 version, this works fine. However, in Access 2007, all of the fields that are coming from the "NewSheet" form are null due to type conversion errors.  How would I tell access that the NewBatch# textbox contains a number? Why did it used to work on Access 97?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I enclose the [Forms]![SpecificForm]![FormObject] with CInt(   ) then it works.

I don't know why Access 97 allowed it. Hmm, sometimes framing a question well leads me to my own answer.